# OpenVZ with RHEL6 kernel & page cache?

Tags: linux, kernel, openvz, rhel6

After upgrading kernel from debian 2.6.32-openvz-amd64 to RHEL6 2.6.32-042stab035.1, I have problem with kernel page cache.

Looks like no OpenVZ containers use page cache and now I have 10-15GB free RAM and only 3-5GB cache generated by mysql server that runs on VE0.

There's no such problem with debian kernel, but all RHEL6 kernels I've tried had the same sympthoms.

```
MemTotal:       24677212 kB
MemFree:        10462364 kB   
Buffers:          467596 kB
Cached:          6487520 kB    
SwapCached:            0 kB    
Active:          9149776 kB    
Inactive:        3396248 kB
```

Any ideas what's going on with RHEL6 kernel? How could I make container use cache?

Comment: You are running mysql server on the hardware node?

Comment: Yea, MySQL is running on VE0, and on VE0 cache is working fine. Prblems are only with containers. They using around 200-400MB cache as dcache and inode cache.

Answer (score 0):

File a bug http://bugzilla.openvz.org/ - they will help resolve this.

Comment: Yeah, i've already posted it few days ago, but i suspect its a possible misconfigration issue. All VEs were configured while running at debian kernel, maybe something was radically changed at RHEL6? Something with VSwap?